# Making checked boxes put multiline text into a label

Tags: vb.net, button, label

So I have 4 check boxes and if one of them is checked, I would like to put that text into a label.

My problem is when one box is checked, it just has that text in the label but not the other checked ones. I want it to have a new line for each box that is checked to put new line text into the label.

How would I be able to have the program go through the check boxes, and if they are checked put that text into a label and for the next box checked start a new line and put that text there?

To be put under a button click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty, but if I understand what you are asking for this should work.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Label1.Text = ""

    If (CheckBox1.Checked) Then
        Label1.Text &= CheckBox1.Text & vbCrLf
    End If

    If (CheckBox2.Checked) Then
        Label1.Text &= CheckBox2.Text & vbCrLf
    End If

    If (CheckBox3.Checked) Then
        Label1.Text &= CheckBox3.Text & vbCrLf
    End If

    If (CheckBox4.Checked) Then
        Label1.Text &= CheckBox4.Text & vbCrLf
    End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: vbCrLf is a carriage return line feed. Much like if you wanted to tab indent in a string you would need to use vbTab. Dim strHello As String = "Hello " & vbTab & "World!".

Answer (score 0):

Put all your `CheckBox`es in the same container. In this example, they are all contained within `Panel1`. This gets all the `Text` properties of the `CheckBox`es which are checked, and puts the `Text` in `Label1.Text`. When nothing is selected, an `Exception` is thrown (Sequence contains no elements).

```
Try
    Label1.Text = Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox). _
        Where(Function(arg) arg.Checked). _
        Select(Function(arg) arg.Text). _
        Aggregate(Function(aggregate, nextItem) aggregate & Environment.NewLine & nextItem)
Catch ex As Exception
    Label1.Text = "Nothing selected"
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

[**Note:** Tested with `IDE`]

```
 Private Sub Common_Cheked_Change_Handler(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
 ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles _
 CheckBox1.CheckedChanged, CheckBox2.CheckedChanged, _
 CheckBox3.CheckedChanged, CheckBox4.CheckedChanged

        Label1.Text = String.Empty

        Label1.Text = If(CheckBox1.Checked = True, CheckBox1.Text & vbCrLf, String.Empty) & _
         If(CheckBox2.Checked = True, CheckBox2.Text & vbCrLf, String.Empty) & _
          If(CheckBox3.Checked = True, CheckBox3.Text & vbCrLf, String.Empty) & _
           If(CheckBox4.Checked = True, CheckBox4.Text, String.Empty)

 End Sub
```